# A Question about Algebraic Integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need to prove a lemma, which uses the following fact:

If $\alpha$ is an algebraic number of degree $m$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $\mu(\alpha)$ to be max$\{ |\alpha_i| \}$, where $\alpha_1=\alpha$, $\alpha_2$, ..., $\alpha_m$ are roots of the corresponding equation of $\alpha$. And if $A$ is an integer such that $A\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, then

$A\mu(\alpha)\geq 1$. I have tried to solve the problem by analyzing some terms of the corresponding equation, but failed. I am wondering are there some theorems that I can apply or can this be solved by some direct methods? Thanks!

Comment: The common name of the "corresponding equation" of $\alpha$ is "minimal polynomial" of $\alpha$. You may be interested to know that $\mu(\alpha)$ is usually called the *house* of $\alpha$.

Comment: As a side note: now that you know how to prove that $\mu(\alpha) \geq 1$ for every algebraic integer $\alpha$, can you prove that (for $\alpha$ algebraic integer) $\mu(\alpha) = 1$ iff $\alpha$ is a root of unity?

Answer (score 3):

Since we have $\sigma(A\alpha) = A \sigma(\alpha)$ for any homomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb Q(\alpha) \to \mathbb C$, we deduce $\mu(A\alpha) = |A| \mu(\alpha)$. Hence we can assume $A=1$ and that $\alpha$ itself is integral over $\mathbb Z$. So we are down to show: Any monic irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$ has a root with absolute value at least $1$. But this is trivial since the product of all roots is well known to be the constant term of $f$ (up to a sign), in particular at least of absolute value $1$.

Comment: Meh, you beat me to it... (+1) :P